# ¿Como inicializar una DataTable?

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

tengo un problema para inicializar una DataTable de JavaScript y quería saber si alguien me podría ayudar a saber la razón, la DataTable es un plugin que coloca las tablas por decirlo de alguna manera, mas dinámicas a continuación los codigos. De ante mano, muchas gracias.

 
Codigo JavaScript donde relleno la tabla, al final está el comando para inicializarla

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
    function obtener_categorias() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'actionphp/fetchCategories.php',
            method: 'post',
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    obtener_categorias();
    $('.categorias').DataTable();
});
```

Codigo PHP donde obtengo los datos de la base de datos:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consult = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM categorias");
echo "
    <table id='categorias' class='table table-striped categorias'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Categoria Id </th>
                <th> Nombre categoria </th>
                <th> Estado </th>
                <th> Acciones </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
";

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$result['categoria_id']."</td>
            <td>".$result['nombre_categoria']."</td>
            <td>".$result['estado']."</td>

        </tr>
    ";
}

echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: Hola @Giovanni, tienes que tener en cuenta que $.ajax es una llamada asyncrona por ende te tocaría mover la línea que inicializa Datatable dentro del success del ajax

Comment: ¡Gracias! Me ha funcionado y lo recordapré para no cometer errores del mismo tipo, donde puedo dejar que tu comentario me ayudó?

Comment: Al lado izquierdo del comentario, puede que te salga una flechita hacia arriba, encima de una bandera